Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и" в данном сложносочинённом предложении?
Что же она всё-таки имела в виду? Знает ли Максим что-нибудь об этом (,) и стоит ли об этом расспрашивать? Здесь две грамматические основы, но почему-то кажется, что запятая здесь будет лишней. Может, всё дело в предшествующем предложении, которое раскрывает смысл сочетания "об этом"?

Правильно:
Что же она всё-таки имела в виду? Знает ли Максим что-нибудь об этом и стоит ли об этом расспрашивать?
Запятая перед союзом И в ССП не ставится по правилу Розенталя:
3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в 
сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав 
в качестве частей входят:
1) вопросительные предложения: Это кто такие и что им 
надобно? (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; Который 
теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?; 
Когда состоится конференция и какова повестка дня?; Вы 
придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?;

Вариант правки: Знает ли Максим что-нибудь об этом и стоит ли его расспрашивать?
